# Residential requirement for Canadian living abroad to collect pensions?

Tags: canada, retirement, non-resident, pension

I have been told by numerous individuals that one is required to return to Canada for a certain period of time, whilst living abroad, in order to continue to collect my Senior benefits from the federal government. Is this true and what is the requirement?

Comment: Which benefits are you referring to: benefits like CPP and OAS that most Canadians qualify for, or, say, a government pension earned from a previous job in the public sector?

Comment: Regarding OAS: The [CRA Site](https://www.canada.ca/en/services/benefits/publicpensions/cpp/old-age-security/eligibility.html) described eligibility and how much you are entitled to depending on how many years you have lived in Canada since the age of 18. You need to have lived in Canada for at least 6 months + 1 day for each year you claim eligibility. You can claim while living abroad, but eligibility is more restrictive.

Comment: I did read and understand that information but what I was really looking for (I am a Canadian, born and bred) is how often and for how long would I need to return to Canada to continue to collect my Canada Pension Benefits.

Comment: I am referring to CPP and OAS pension benefits - the only pensions I will have.